# Using sed to append part of a string to the front of the string

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed

In Linux, I have a string and wish to use sed to append a number found in the string to the front of it, with a colon afterwards. For example, I have the string

```
word word word 01 word word 02 word word word word 03 word
```

and wish to have

```
03:word word word 01 word word 02 word word word word 03 word
```

I can use

```
sed 's/^/:/'
```

to append the colon to the front, but for each individual string I want to copy the number in the 03 position to the front as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
sed -r 's/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)/\2:\1\2/' <<< "$string"
```

I'm using the substitute command `s`. `(.*[^0-9])` captures (greedy) everything until the last number in the string into subpattern 1. The number itself ([0-9]+) goes to subpattern 2.

In the replacement pattern we print subpattern 2 in front of 2 and add the colon between them.

Comment: Great, thanks - this is what I was looking for. However, some of the numbers I am copying are decimals, like 26.51; I'm guessing I have to edit the regex expression [0-9]+, but I'm brand new to regex and I don;t really know how. Are you able to help? Thanks

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907413/using-sed-to-append-part-of-a-string-to-the-front-of-the-string/31907980#31907980) will handle decimal numbers

Comment: Thanks  
      sed -r 's/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/\2:\1\2/' <<< "$string" 

works too :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're treating the input like columns, it might be better served by awk.

Here's a column-ish approach with sed:

```
sed -r 's/^(([^ ]+ ){11})([^ ]+)/\3:\1\3/'
```

(if your "03" column ever gets changed, just change the `{11}` to `{yournewcolumnnumber-1})

---

with awk, things are a bit more readable

```
awk '{print $12 ":" $0}'
```

Comment: Cheers! Haven't come across awk before, but will look into. Thanks for your help :)